# how to click html button programmatically on Asp button click?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have created popup window using bootstrap with some Text box.This popup window show on my html button click.I will created multiple Asp Button on page-load.I will try to each asp button click after retrieve some value into text box in popup window.
i try to each asp button click after show on popup window.but,not retrieve value.so,i have one idea my asp button click after automatically click my html button.how i can do this.please help me.followed my code.
**my html button**

```
 <button id="btn2" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create New</button>
```

### webform1.aspx

```
  <form id="form1" runat="server" class="table table-striped " cellspacing="0" width="100%">           
       <button id="btn2" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Create New</button>                       
  <asp:Table ID="Table1" 
            runat="server" 
            class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%"
            >
            <asp:TableHeaderRow runat="server"     >
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>Code</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>Name</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>Descrption</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                 <asp:TableHeaderCell>Sort</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                <asp:TableHeaderCell>Enable</asp:TableHeaderCell>
                 <asp:TableHeaderCell>Action</asp:TableHeaderCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
      </asp:Table>



  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Branch </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <%-- <p>Some text in the modal.</p>--%>





        <div class="span3">




                <div class="field">
                    <label for="firstname">Code:</label>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_BranchCode" value="" placeholder="Branch Code"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                </div> <!-- /field -->

                <div class="field">
                    <label for="lastname">Name:</label> 

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_BranchName" value="" placeholder="Branch Name"  runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                </div> <!-- /field -->


                <div class="field">
                    <label for="email">Description:</label>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Descr" value="" placeholder="Description"  runat="server" Height="68px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                </div> <!-- /field -->

                <div class="field">
                    <label for="password">Sort:</label>

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Sort" value="" placeholder="Sort"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div> <!-- /field -->

                <div class="field">
                    <label for="confirm_password">Enable:</label>


                       <asp:DropDownList ID="dd_Enable" runat="server" Width="160px">
                           <asp:ListItem>True</asp:ListItem>
                           <asp:ListItem>False</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div> <!-- /field -->




            <div class="login-actions">             

                <asp:Button ID="btn_Add" class="button btn btn-primary btn-large" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btn_Add_Click" />


            </div> <!-- .actions -->




        </div>  



                </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

### webform1.aspx.cs

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {



                    RetrieveAzureAsync(sender,e);

            }
            async private void RetrieveAzureAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               IMobileServiceTable<BranchList>  BranchTable = client.GetTable<BranchList>();

                List<BranchList> items_list = await BranchTable
                   .Where(branchitem => branchitem.Enable == true)
                   .ToListAsync();

                int size = items_list.Count();
                if (size > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    {
                        TableRow row = new TableRow();
                        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
                        TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
                        TableCell cell4 = new TableCell();
                        TableCell cell5 = new TableCell();
                        TableCell cell6 = new TableCell();
                        cell1.Text = items_list[i].BranchCode;
                        cell2.Text = items_list[i].BranchName;
                        cell3.Text = items_list[i].Descr;
                        cell4.Text = Convert.ToString(items_list[i].Sort);
                        cell5.Text = Convert.ToString(items_list[i].Enable);
//my multiple asp button
                        Button btn = new Button();
                        btn.Text = "Edit";
                        btn.ID = items_list[i].Id;
                        btn.Width = 70;
                        btn.CssClass = "btn btn-info btn-lg";
                        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);




                        cell6.Controls.Add(btn);

                        row.Cells.Add(cell1);
                        row.Cells.Add(cell2);
                        row.Cells.Add(cell3);
                        row.Cells.Add(cell4);
                        row.Cells.Add(cell5);
                        row.Cells.Add(cell6);
                        Table1.Rows.Add(row);

                    }
                }
    }

     void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    //what code for click btn2 programmatically


            }
```

Comment: Have you tried with runat=server?

Comment: Just put runat=server in button tag... then only you can Access it in the Server side Program(C#)

Comment: i try  <asp:Button ID="btn2" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" runat="server" Text="Button" />  but this only show popup window

Comment: please any one help me

Answer (score 1):

I have using simple way now.I have used `jQuery` refer this side http://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/605/ .Thanks for replay all.

Answer (score 0):

on client side

```
<script>
function btnclick()
{
      $("#btn2").trigger("click");
}

</script>
```

on servse side

```
void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "btnclick", "btnclick()", true);
            }
```